# Would RSA-encrypting a private key for itself constitute a vulnerability?

Tags: cryptanalysis, rsa, pgp

I'm planning to encrypt some individual files for storage, using the GnuPG implementation of RSA. If I happened to encrypt the private key corresponding to the public key used for encrypting -- either as an internal GnuPG file or an ASCII-armored exported key -- would this constitute a vulnerability?

The key in question is password-protected, but I'd be interested in both situations.

Answer (score 8):

If there is a vulnerability in encrypting a RSA private key with the corresponding public key, when the private key is password-protected, then it mechanically implies a vulnerability in the password-based protection scheme: if an attacker gets a copy of the password-encrypted key (without the password), he can encrypt it with the public key himself; so an attack on the result (RSA encryption of the password-protected private key, leading to a private key compromise) is readily turned into an attack on the password-based encryption.

Without password encryption, things are a bit less clear. Consider the following hypothetical RSA-like cryptosystem:

- $n = pq$ is the public modulus, with public exponent $e$;
- private key is $p$ (knowing $p$, $n$ and $e$ is sufficient to recompute the private exponent $d$);
- encryption uses no padding (message $m$ is encrypted by computing $m^e \mod n$ directly).

Then the encryption of the private key yields $p^e \mod n$, an integer which is a multiple of $p$ (it is equal to $p^e-kpq$ for some integer $k$) but not of $q$. Therefore, a simple [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between that value and $n$ reveals $p$.

Now, the real RSA has padding, and, more importantly (here), when used in GnuPG, is an [hybrid encryption scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_encryption): what RSA actually processes is a random value, from which is derived a symmetric encryption key, which is then used to encrypt the actual data. For RSA-encryption of the (unprotected) private key to be a vulnerability, it would require the symmetric encryption to somehow transport unscathed algebraic properties from the private key structure to the modular exponentiation. This is highly improbable and my *gut feeling* is that there is no problem here. But still, no formal proof.

Why would you want to do that, anyway ? To do anything with an encrypted message, you have to know the decryption key -- and if you already know the decryption key, why would you care about obtaining it *again* from the decryption ?

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. Since I'm planning to encrypt and store my home directory, I'm a bit wary about what would happen if I've left my private key somewhere or `~/.gnupg` keeps it.